# OverflowException with Delimon Directory.Exists

Tags: c#, .net, overflowexception

I have a really strange error, with Delimon.Io library, I got an OverflowException when I call a Directory.Exists for an existing directory, ie.

```
Delimon.Win32.IO.Directory.Exists(@"c:\temp")
```

The error occours only if I issue the call in a specific service, no error if I run the same code in unit testing project.

What could be the project settings that makes this simple call fail? (Clearly calling a

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:\\temp")
```

correctly returns `true`.

Comment: Shameless self-plug: I've written [a similar library for dealing with long paths](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths), maybe you want to give it a try, to see whether it brings the same error.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. The problem is that I used delimon lots of time in the past without any problem, and I got this error only on that specific project. I do not know why it happens.

Comment: Sounds like a specific issue with that library.  Probably best to contact the author.

Comment: Actually there are comments in TechNet page by people having the very same problem and no answer. I've substituted the library with very little effort with this library (https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath) and it seems to work well until now.